# ImportError: Error loading shared library libpq.so.5: No such file or directory (needed by psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so

Tags: psycopg2, alpine-linux

having issues importing pycopg2 on python:3.9-alpine.
my docker file has

```
RUN apk add --no-cache gcc libffi-dev musl-dev postgresql-dev make curl git python3-dev openssl-dev cargo make
```

and installing psycopg2 binary and pool

```
psycopg2 = {extras = ["binary","pool"], version = "^2.9.4"}
```

still seeing import when try to import psycopg2

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/main.py", line 11, in <module>
    import psycopg2
  File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
ImportError: Error loading shared library libpq.so.5: No such file or directory (needed by /root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
```

Comment: Try `whereis libpq.so.5` to see if it actually exists on your computer.

Comment: I see libpq is installed as well. 
#6 7.698 (30/55) Installing openssl-dev (3.1.0-r4)
#6 7.732 (31/55) Installing libpq (15.3-r0)
#6 7.750 (32/55) Installing libpq-dev (15.3-r0)
#6 7.777 (33/55) Installing libecpg (15.3-r0)
#6 7.794 (34/55) Installing libecpg-dev (15.3-r0)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are installing `psycopg2` package in its binary form. On Alpine Linux, this doesn't work, since it is a musl-libc based Linux distribution - whereas most Linux distributions (and binaries) are based on glibc (GNU libc).
The binary name provides a good hint - note the `gnu` in the name, `_psycopg.cpython-39-x86_64-linux` - which means the binary is compatible with glibc. It could be used with mainstream Linux distributions such as Ubuntu, Debian and Fedora, but not with Alpine.

The simple solution is installing `psycopg2` in its Pythonic form, meaning that `pip` compiles the package sources during installation. This should result in a functional `psycopg2` package.

Possible Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache gcc libffi-dev musl-dev postgresql-dev make curl git python3-dev openssl-dev cargo make
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install psycopg2
```

When building the image, note the install log:

```
STEP 4/4: RUN pip3 install psycopg2
Collecting psycopg2
  Downloading psycopg2-2.9.6.tar.gz (383 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 384.0/384.0 kB 2.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Building wheels for collected packages: psycopg2
  Building wheel for psycopg2 (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for psycopg2 (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for psycopg2: filename=psycopg2-2.9.6-cp39-cp39-linux_x86_64.whl size=466949 sha256=96af4e9ee13434705ad997f39c6c40bda2f78d59a9961084af69e11fdb286109
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/e0/1d/09/2bc95af38e38d614767de0126fbf27a55a5c277f612aa6a51f
Successfully built psycopg2
Installing collected packages: psycopg2
Successfully installed psycopg2-2.9.6
```

When running the container, now you should be able to import the package successfully:

```
Python 3.9.16 (main, May 11 2023, 23:44:06)
[GCC 12.2.1 20220924] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import psycopg2
>>>
```